# PHP exec() function to PING is not working for Cpanel

Tags: php, centos, exec, cpanel, ping

I have created an application to monitor `Network IP` or `Server Status`. It is working fine for windows `xampp server` and also tested on `linux centos 6.0`. Both are working good. But When i uploaded the script to a website where cpanel is installed and my script is not working there. That is a linux hosting server

My Ping Command for Windows:

```
$exec = exec( "ping www.google.com -n 3 ". $output, $status );
```

My Ping Command for Centos:

```
$exec = exec( "ping www.google.com -c 3 ". $output, $status );
```

both `$output` and `$status` variable is returning accurate values. But in cpanel `$output` is blank and `$status` variable is returning 2 instead of 0 or 1

Need Help
Thanks,

Comment: Change the period to a comma (between your command and `$output`).  You are not getting an error because it is a concatenation operator (technically, this is syntactically correct), but it is also not filling the variable with data...

Comment: i have tried by changing period to comma but the result is same

Comment: Many hosting providers who supply cpanel type services don't allow the use of `exec()`; You might verify this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if your host provider is allowing the use this function if yes , so 
try using the exec like this:

`$exec = exec( "ping www.google.com -c 3 ", $output, $status );`

if its not working you can try another php function like exec:

`system('ping www.google.com -c 3 ', $output);`

you can use nagios for monitoring and build your application on top of nagios

Answer (score 0):

1. Check first, exec function is disabled by your Hosting Provider or not by using the given function. This function will list out all the disabled functions by your hosting provider.

   ```
   function disabled_functions(){
     $disabled = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
     return $disabled;
   }
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r(disabled_functions());
   ```
2. If exec exists in the output of the above disabled_functions(), then you have to consult your hosting provider to allow shell access and exec.
   Generally hosting providers disable shell access and functions similar to exec because of security issues.